Setting variable (ORACLE_BASE) for oracle user | Installing Oracle 23
Goal: Install Oracle 23 into /u00/app (and not the default, /opt/oracle).
Problem: Oracle installs into /opt/oracle (I assume the variable ORACLE_BASE etc. is not properly set / read for user oracle during install)
Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/ladbi/about-the-oracle-inventory-directory-and-installation.html

Here is what I have so far, I run this as sudo /u00/oracle-install.sh:
#!/bin/bash

# run as: sudo /u00/oracle-install.sh

#
# Set environment variables
# --------------------------------
export ORACLE_ROOT="/u00"
export ORACLE_BASE="${ORACLE_ROOT}/app/oracle"
export ORACLE_HOME="${ORACLE_BASE}/product/free-23ai-1.0-1/dbhome_1"
export ORACLE_INVENTORY="$(dirname $ORACLE_BASE)/oraInventory"
export ORACLE_DATA="${ORACLE_ROOT}/oradata"

# preinstall package
dnf -y localinstall /us3/dl/oracle-database-preinstall-23ai-1.0-2.el9.x86_64.rpm

# main package
dnf -y localinstall /us3/dl/oracle-database-free-23ai-1.0-1.el9.x86_64_.rpm

What am I missing?
